# Visual Studio Website: Can't create an SQL Database!

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, local-database

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 SP1 with SQL Server 2008.

I'am trying to add an SQL Server File (MDF) in my Website project. Then I get the following error:

```
Connections to SQL Server files (*.mdf) require SQL Server Express 2005 to function properly. Please verify...
```

I've been using Google without any results, and I'm in deep need for help..

I've tried the following things to fix it, without succes:

- Changing instance names so they
  should fit
- Attaching the database in the
  management studio
- Uninstall/Install Visual Studio
- Uinstall/Install SQL Server 2005 AND
  2008

All in all, this is a REALLY annoying error and it just should work..

Comment: favored... I had/have this same problem... all I know is that it has to do with SQL Server 2008 and Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

Answer (score 3):

Adding an .MDF to your VS project requires a SQL Server **EXPRESS** edition - only those are able to attach a .mdf file from the `App_Data` directory.

The full versions (Developer, Web, Standard, Enterprise) of SQL Server cannot use the `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf;` feature that is the basis of this feature in Visual Studio.

If you have a full SQL Server edition on your machine (or on a server), you need to use that SQL Server in a more traditional way: use SQL Server Management Studio (or the Server Explorer inside Visual Studio) to create databases and database objects like tables, and connect to them using a classic ADO.NET connection string (`server=name;database=name;...`)